# Where is max_obstacle_height in an Obstacle_Layer measured from?

Tags: navigation, ros2, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know where does the local costmap take the origin to measure the height of the obstacles. Is it from the coordinate frame of the sensor, from the coordinate frame of the robot, or from the coordinate frame of the map?

In case it is measured from the coordinate frame of the map is there a way to change the coordinate frame to the one of the robot?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404395/where-is-max_obstacle_height-in-an-obstacle_layer-measured-from?/) by [marpeja](https://answers.ros.org/users/101482/marpeja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2022-07-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-07-29**:
In ros1, my recollection is that each sensor point is converted to the move_base global frame (typically `map`) and then compared. But I don't know if ros2 has the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @Mike Scheutzow mentioned in the comments, it seems it is the same situation in Nav2 as in ROS1:

- https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/pull/2922 (ROS2, mentioning one below from ROS1)
- https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/noetic-devel/costmap_2d/cfg/ObstaclePlugin.cfg

> ```
> gen.add("max_obstacle_height", double_t, 0, "The maximum height of
> any obstacle to be inserted into the costmap in meters.", 2, 0, 50)
> ```

- https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/pull/2592#pullrequestreview-779145070 (older one)

and

- http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/obstacles

> ```
> ~<name>/<source_name>/max_obstacle_height (double, default: 2.0)
> ```
>
> The maximum height in meters of a sensor reading considered valid. This
> is usually set to be slightly higher
> than the height of the robot. Setting
> this parameter to a value greater than
> the global max_obstacle_height
> parameter has no effect. Setting this
> parameter to a value less than the
> global max_obstacle_height will filter
> out points from this sensor above that
> height.
>
> ```
> ~<name>/<source_name>/min_obstacle_height (double, default: 0.0)
> ```
>
> The minimum height in meters of a sensor reading considered valid. This
> is usually set to be at ground height,
> but can be set higher or lower based
> on the noise model of your sensor.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1